# Is any value of $(\sqrt i)^{\ln(i)}$ real?

Tags: complex-numbers

Is any value of $(\sqrt i)^{\ln(i)}$ real?

Inspired by similar expressions, I was playing around a bit on julia prompt and typed $(\sqrt i)^{\ln(i)}$

```
julia> sqrt(im)^log(im)
0.29121293321402086 + 0.0im
```

It (surprisingly?) computes a real number value.

Then I tried to prove this is a valid value. I assume it is not too hard, but nevertheless, I could not readily prove it...

So, sorry to ask: how to prove that none or any or all value(s) of $(\sqrt{i})^{\ln i}$ is, or are, real?

Comment: You are applying three multivalued functions here!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : thanks for reply ! so would **any** of the values be real? I will adjust title.

Comment: If you take the principal value of the root, the logarithm and the exponential, the value is $e^{-\pi^2/8}$ which follows directly from applying the definitions.

Comment: @jjagmath : thanks for solution which Julia interpreter confirms true. I apologize for not having seen it and dared considering to ask,

Comment: $a^b = e^{b\ln a}$ and $\ln i = i\frac{\pi}{2}$.  You should be able to work things out from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(\sqrt{i})^{\ln{i}}$$
$$= \exp((\ln{i})(\ln\sqrt{i}))$$
$$= \exp((\ln{i})(\frac{1}{2}\ln i))$$
$$= \exp(\frac{1}{2}(\ln{i})^2)$$
$$= \exp(\frac{1}{2}(i\frac{\pi}{2})^2)$$
$$= \exp(\frac{-\pi^2}{8})$$
$$\approx 0.291213$$

Comment: thanks for explicit proof I could not easily find